# Creating a fishing pole with unreal engine 4

Tags: game-physics, unreal-engine4

Trying to figure out a way for creating a fishing pole in UE4.
The goal is to essentially have the correct bending simulation of the pole.
It looks like the best way to utilize a Bernoulli Euler beam equation while adjusting the pulling forces based on the previous pole part.

Am I thinking in the correct way, or there is an easier approach to animating the Pole?
I'm also considering some sort of rigging + joint transformation based on this, however, not entirely clear how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

My first try would be to keep it simple, so I would create bones for each section and build an IK Chain leveraging also Joint Target. Some BluePrint tweak might be necessary, but that is where I would start experimenting.

~Pino